# Make logon screen visible/invisible javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, visible

I'm trying to make my logon screen appear and dissappear when a certain button is being pressed but my code doesn't seem to work and always gives a problem

```
document.getElementById('logon').style.visibility='hidden';
        function showlogon(){
            document.getElementById('logon').style.visibility="visible";
        }
```

this is my javascript code it must be standard be hidden

```
<div id="logon">
                    <form name="login" method="post">
                        Username:<input name="username" type="text" size="14"/><br>
                        Password:<input name="password" type="password" size="14"/><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

this is the form that must be hidden by default

Comment: And how do you do this?

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery. Your code looks fine, there must be something else you are missing.

Comment: if I use jqeury is use it like this $('logon').hide(); but it will give the same problem. I'm using netbeans and it gives an error on style but it will continue to run it.

Comment: I found the solution. the javascript code above the if statement is'nt being runt when the page is loaded so I added a function onload in my body so it will run the function and hide the "logon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
                <div id="logon" style="display: none;">
                <form name="login" method="post">
                    Username:<input name="username" type="text" size="14"/><br>
                    Password:<input name="password" type="password" size="14"/><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="button"><button onClick="show()">Show Screen</button></div>
            <script>
            function show() {
                document.getElementById('logon').style.display = 'block'; // Show the #logon div
                document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = '<button onClick="hide()">Hide Screen</button>';
            }

            function hide() {
                document.getElementById('logon').style.display = 'none'; // Hide the #logon div
                document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = '<button onClick="show()">Show Screen</button>';
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit bulky and repetitive? It's a toggle you want, not 2 different functions who just repeat the code with minor changes. Four `document.getElementById()` when only one is required. Unnecessary markup just in order to handle the JavaScript states of the button.

Comment: Just showing so that if he decideds to use just. the show or hide function

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small simple utility method for what you want to do:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8XPR/

```
function get(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

function toggle(id) {
    el = get(id);
    el.style.display='none'==el.style.display?'':"none";
};
```